# How can I transparently redirect a Python import?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm looking for a way to emulate symlinks for Python imports. I'd like to be able to unzip the following folder structure in-place without duplicating files:

```
root
├─ python_lib
│  └─ my_utils
│     ├─ __init__.py
│     └─ etc.py
├─ app1
├─ app2
└─ app3
   ├─ lib
   │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  └─ my_utils.py
   └─ run.py
```

`app3/run.py` contains this:

```
from lib.my_utils import etc

etc.pancakes()
```

I'd like the code to use the `etc` located in `python_lib/my_utils/`. Is there anything I can put in `app3/lib/my_utils.py` so that Python >= 3.1 will transparently import the `python_lib/my_utils/` folder (using relative paths and `..`), and subpackages will also work?

Answer (score 8):

You will have to execute *something* before `app3/run.py` reaches the import statement.

```
import python_lib
import sys
sys.modules['lib'] = python_lib
# ...
from lib import etc
print etc.__file__
print dir(etc)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add this path into `sys.path`. For example:

```
lib_path = os.path.abspath( os.path.split( os.getcwd()+"/"+sys.argv[0] )[0]+"/../_lib/my_utils/" )
sys.path.append(lib_path)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if put in `my_utils.py`, since the import location is already resolved by then. If I run this before my main code, it still won't work, because each subpackage in `my_utils` would appear top-level to Python, and then relative imports within `my_utils` wouldn't work.

Comment: I usually set paths from my `run` script. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense.
You could also try to play around with `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. More info here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 1):

Add `__init__.py` to the `python_lib` folder
`app3/run.py` contains

```
import python_lib.my_utils
import os

sys.modules['lib.my_utils'] = python_lib.my_utils
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to your directory structure to simplify the example:

- create root/python_lib/__init__.py
- rename root/python_lib to root/lib
- replace root/app3/lib/ with lib.py

Place the following code in root/app3/lib.py

```py
import os
import sys

pth = os.path.sep.join(sys.argv[0].split(os.path.sep)[0:-2])
sys.path.insert(0, pth)
del sys.modules[__name__]
import lib
```

Essentially, we have a dummy module that replaces its own reference in sys.modules with a reference to a module or package in another location.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  (Yes, put it at `app3/lib/my_utils.py`.)

```
import os
_f = os.path.realpath(__file__)
_f = os.path.dirname(_f)
_f = os.path.dirname(_f)
_f = os.path.dirname(_f)
_f = os.path.join(_f, 'python_lib')
def f():
    path = sys.path
    path.insert(0, _f)
    sys.modules['lib.my_utils'] = __import__('my_utils')
    path.pop(0)
f()
```

Answer (score -1):

Very late to this, but this is incredibly easy. All you need to do is modify the `__path__` attribute of your package so it points to the folder where your modules are. This will require `lib` to be a package, not just a module (ie. a folder with an `__init__.py`). By default `__path__` is a one element list that contains the path of folder that is the package -- `['/path/to/lib']`. Meaning, that by default, python searches for sub modules in the module folder (seems like a very logical thing to do).

You can alter the contents of path to point to where ever you want, but it must contain absolute paths. If you only *append* `path/to/lib_python` then python will search lib first, find my_utils.py and then stop. So in that case you will need to delete `my_utils.py` or put the new path at the front of `__path__` so that location is searched first. This also means that the `lib` folder can contain its own supplementary modules to the shared libraries and still work.

In practice:

lib/__init__.py

```
from os.path import join
__path__.insert(0, join(__path__[0], "..", "..", "python_lib"))
```