# Is it possible to make subpackage appear as the actual package

Tags: python, package, python-import

I came around [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304999/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-python/) and got quite disappointed by how the [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow) developers try to make the `tensorflow` directory appear as the actual package, whereas the actual package root is actually `tensorflow/python`. By using a `__init__.py` file of the form

```
from tensorflow.python import *
del python
```

they try to achieve this goal. This results in some inconsistent behaviour (at least so it seems to me) when working with the package, e.g.

```
import tensorflow.python                # seems to work
tensorflow.python                       # AttributeError: no attribute 'python'
from tensorflow.python import Session   # works as expected
tensorflow.python.Session               # AttributeError: no attribute 'python'
from tensorflow import python           # works as expected

tensorflow.nn                           # works as expected
import tensorflow.nn                    # ImportError: no module 'tensorflow.nn'
tensorflow.nn.tanh                      # works as expected
from tensorflow.nn import tanh          # ImportError: no module 'tensorflow.nn'
```

Now, I was wondering whether/how it could be possible to avoid most/all of these issues to get a more consistent behaviour. The first set of inconsistencies could be easily resolved by not deleting the `python` attribute. However, given that the goal would be to make the complete package appear as if it is a sub-package, this might not be entirely satisfactory.

To keep things simple, let's consider the following package structure

```
package/
    __init__.py
    api/
        __init__.py
        code.py
```

where `package/api/code.py` looks something like

```
def a(): 
    return 'alpha'
def b(): 
    return 'bravo'
```

and `package/api/__init__.py` would be

```
import package.api.code
```

would it be possible to create `package/__init__.py` so that the following works

```
import package.api                      # ImportError: no module 'package.api'
package.api                             # AttributeError: no attribute 'api'
from package.api import code            # ImportError: no module 'package.api'
package.api.code                        # AttributeError: no attribute 'api'
from package import api                 # ImportError: cannot import 'api'

package.code                            # works as expected
import package.code                     # works as above
package.code.a                          # works as expected
from package import a                   # correctly imports function a
```

I believe that the last four lines of code should give the expected result by adding to `sys.modules`, but I do not seem to be able to find a way to make `import package.api` fail.

Would anyone have an idea on how this could be done? Feel free to point me to use-cases that I am overlooking or should consider to achieve the above-mentioned goal.

Comment: Can you try: import package.code as code

Comment: @PeterMajko What do you mean with that? This should normally work if `import package.code` works...

Comment: It works perfectly fine if you use "import x from y as z": [Check this image](https://ibb.co/kHkPL6)

Comment: @PeterMajko I know, I noticed that `from tensorflow import python` does indeed work (I edited my question accordingly), but should it? I assume the idea of `del python` in `tensorflow/__init__.py` is to make the tensorflow package appear as if it were `tensorflow/python`. In this case, this is not the kind of behaviour that I would like to see.

Comment: They have some reason to do it like that. Perhaps ask them why they took this approach? :)

Comment: @PeterMajko Probably, but I am not interested in altering tensorflow. I would merely like to know whether it is possible to do something like this...

Comment: "would it be possible to create package/__init__.py so that the following works" - should the 'following' work from outside the package? What I mean, let's say I create a 'main.py' outside the package. And 'import package.code' should work from main.py?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - I must say that I literally hate "shady" techniques like this. It has a bad effect on various IDE intellisense and makes the library structure less understandable. But still...

If you want the submodule code.py to act as an actual subpackage, you need to create a dummy module:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    api/
        __init__.py
        code.py
    code/
        __init__.py
```

Add this in code/__init__py:

```
from package.api.code import *
```

And this in package/__init__.py:

```
from package.code import *
```

And then this part should work as intended:

```
import package.code            # works as expected
package.code                   # works as expected
package.code.a                 # works as expected
from package import a          # works as expected
```

If you further add this to the package/__init__.py:

```
import package.api
del package.api
```

You basically disconnect user from accessing package.api, but nothing else, and they can still access the submodule through subpackage using 'from x import y':

```
import package.api            # works
package.api.a()               # AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'api'

import package.api.code       # works
package.api.code.a()          # AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'api'

from package.api import code  # works
code.a()                      # works

from package import api       # works
api.code.a()                  # AttributeError: module 'package.api' has no attribute 'code'
```

Comment: I actually would like to see consistent behaviour: if the import `import package.api` works, `package.api.a()` should work as well. However, it would be even more interesting to have `import package.api` fail with an `ImportError` and keep the `AttributeError` when invoking `package.api.a()`.

Comment: ANother thing is - you really shouldn't do this, if you want to just make it "nice" and promote submodule as a subpackage -.- I would kill people for this

Comment: It is rather easy to make the import consistent (and thus "nice") without tweaking the import system (just get rid of the delete statement, and everything is consistent). I was just wondering what the possibilities/limitations of python are on this subject. Please don't kill me...

Comment: Lol :) It's ok. For all possibilities about import/load I suggest [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). I believe that you would be able to construct something what  works as you describe from all this knowledge - the question would be - why would you do it? :) (no need to answer, haha)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write something that **almost** works (in `package/__init__.py`):

```
import sys

from package.api import *

for key in sys.modules:
    parts = key.split('.')
    if len(parts) > 1 and parts.pop(0) == __name__:
        subkey = parts.pop(0)
        if subkey == 'api' and len(parts) == 0:
            sys.modules['.'.join([__name__, subkey])] = None
        elif subkey == 'api':
            m = sys.modules.pop(key)
            sys.modules['.'.join([__name__] + parts)] = m
del api        
del sys
```

The import errors suggest that it is still quite a hack, but apart from that most all of the examples work as specified **iff** the package has already been loaded once (i.e. if `import package` or alike has been invoked before running the statements from my question). If the first statement is `import package.api`, there is thus no `ImportError` as I would like.

In an attempt to find a solution for this problem, I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24687316/4375377), which practically leads to the same behaviour with much more elegant code:

```
import sys

from package import api

# clean up this module
self = sys.modules.pop(__name__)
del self

# this module becomes hidden module
sys.modules[__name__] = api
sys.modules[api.__name__] = None

del api
del sys
```

However, this still suffers from the problem that if the first import is something like `import package.api`, no `ImportError` is thrown.