# How to convert JFIF to JPEG on AWS Lambda in Python 3.11? Using Pillow gives difficult error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, aws-lambda-layers

I've tried to get Pillow to work on AWS Lambda on x86 using Lambda Layers (I built the python dependency zip using a docker ubuntu image on my computer, and I've also tried building it on a docker Amazon Linux image), but I get errors that I don't know how to fix. The errors seem to throw on the line

```
from PIL import Image
```

The version of Pillow I've installed via lambda layer is 10.0.1
The error that I get is:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/opt/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

This error only happens for me on AWS Lambda, not on any of my local machines.

I don't import '_imaging' anywhere directly in my code, so I guess the import is happening from inside of PIL/__init__.py. (Although when I opened that file, I don't see that import statement directly in that file, either.)

I've tried following advice of a number of other stack overflow answers, including the top answer here: [Python Layer Image Failing: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400740/python-layer-image-failing-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-cannot-i)

The top answer recommends:

> 1. Use an older version of Pillow (pre 2.1.0)
> 2. Find where you are importing _imaging and replace it with the updated from PIL.Image import core as _imaging
> 3. Update to the current version of Pillow

When I tried using an older version of Pillow (2.0.0), I ended up getting the following error instead:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': The _imaging C module is not installed"
```

When I tried looking for where _imaging is getting imported, I was unable to find it (as described above).

And I'm already at the current version of Pillow, so I can't update it.

Please help me figure out what's going wrong! Or if you have an alternative suggestion for a way for me to convert jfif to jpeg, please let me know. I tried imageio, but I'm running into errors on lambda regarding imageio's dependency on numpy.
Thanks!

Comment: Pillow is at version 10 or so, version 2 must be donkeys' years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this in an indirect way. I didn't get the library working on default lambda, but I ended up building a docker container with my code and all my dependencies, and ran it on lambda via ECR. So now my whole code is in a container, not just the layer with dependencies.